# Removing cabinets and matching Ceiling knockdown underneath

Tags: drywall, ceiling

My husband and I recently pulled out some upper cabinets in our kitchen. I want to DIY spray texture the knockdown but the problem I ran into after priming the area is there is a ridge in the ceiling texture where the cabinets used to be. I tried spraying over the ridge but it shows right through. What can I do to make it not look like there was cabinetry there? (I tried to add a picture but it won’t let me :/ )

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. If you post the URL of your picture, someone will be along to edit into your question.

Answer (score 1):

One way to reduce the visible ridge effect is to use sandpaper to taper down the old knock down material along the ridge to smooth it out some. This job will be a bit harder if the old material has coats of paint on it. When I have sanded like this in a similar situation I used 120 weight sandpaper on a hand sanding block.

Note that there will be the urging desire to perform this sanding with a power sander but this is generally not recommended because it is so easy to sand too far and end up tearing up the paper covering of the drywall.